# Trace graph in ns2

Tags: graph, ns2

I have problem to read .tr file in Trace graph.

I have .tr file which is generated by ns2 tcl file.

When i open that file using trace graph ... on terminal it show some think like this .

ERROR: Cannot read the file!
Invalid fid.
Maximal number of lines (1000) has been processed!
ERROR: Cannot read the file!
Invalid fid.

Please help me.

Basically i have 3 .tr file. I want to draw graph using this in trace graph.
Suggest me any good tutorial for trace graph for tr file analysis.

Answer (score 1):

for xgraph you have to give file with only two lines like

```
1 5

5 89
```

8 98 here first row is x axis 2nd is y axis for example save this file as **graph.tr**

now you can execute using xgraph graph.tr here instead of using random values you have to use your QOS valuse such as number of packets received or sent like that..